# Rails redirect without using redirect_to

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails redirect_to method performs some validations on the URI (I believe uses URI.parse) and will throw errors if it contains invalid characters that are un-escaped or simply a malformed uri.

I would really like to implement my own redirect_to method which will simply redirect to any string I give it to, and render a status code of 302.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  Appreciate any help or suggestions

Comment: Can you give an example how the urls you are trying to redirect to look? Why are they invalid? What sense does it make to redirect to an invalid url? The client will probably regard it as invalid and throw an error, too. Please also include the error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `head` method in controller:

`# action method
    def create
      head 302, :location => "http://www.google.com"
    end`